# Whatsapp Cloud API can go live on production

Tags: whatsapp

I have successfully setup my account on whatsapp developer app by meta and can send messages to 5 free users. Now the question is how can I go live with the app. I have no verified business manager account, is that necessary?

What will I need to do after verification of business account? Do I need to generate permanent access token and it would work fine?

Plus I need to know how can I send messages to groups on whatsapp?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to become a verified business account and all would work as you saw with the demo account, with no restriction on the number of destinations.

First 1000 conversations/month it's free, you can check details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing/

Bear in mind, you will NOT be able to message groups with the WA Cloud API. If you need to, you will need to rely on custom APIs that do that. There are some available, see the one shown here:
https://youtu.be/lCmoay0G86M